# LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in Maineng.obj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, objectarx

We are trying to open a c++ project which was built on VS 2010 and Object ARX 2014 in VS 2012 but getting below errors :

LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in Maineng.obj in rxapi.lib

[image]

Could anybody let us know the solution for this error. The Include Path is correctly set to VC++ 2012 installation directory. We have VS 2012 Update 4

Comment: Static libraries must be built with the same compiler version.  Get an update for rxapi.lib from Autodesk.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will try  that